# php - Receive webhook data from hipmob

Tags: php, post, request

I'm trying to receive a webhook from hipmob (live chat app) that should be triggered at a chat event.

Documentation: https://www.hipmob.com/documentation/chat-events.html

I've been following [How to catch the HTTP POST request sent by a Shopify Webhook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10937198/how-to-catch-the-http-post-request-sent-by-a-shopify-webhook) , and i have to say that i am completly new to this. I tried the solution from the first answer but with no success.

this is what i did:

```
<?php
$webhookContent = "";

$webhook = fopen('php://input' , 'rb');
while (!feof($webhook)) {
    $webhookContent .= fread($webhook, 4096);
}
fclose($webhook);

$file = 'webhook.txt';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);

error_log($webhookContent);
?>
```

but with no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solution it with:

```
   <?php

    $entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

    $file = 'webhook.txt';
    // Open the file to get existing content
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    // Append a new person to the file
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $entityBody);

    error_log($webhookContent);
    ?>
```